# HTML5 canvas and scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I have a canvas element of size 1024x768 where I draw a very large image, let's just say with width >> 1024 and height >> 768. The image can be scrolled with normal scrollbars to be seen entirely.

Users can click onto the canvas to add vertices to a polygon: each time a vertex is added, a line from the new vertex to the mouse cursor is drawn.
Each mouse movement onto the canvas updates the canvas in order to redraw such line from the vertex to the new mouse cursor position.

Being the image VERY large, redrawing is very slow, so I'd like to just redraw the currently visible chunk of image or, even better, the "sub-chunk" that is affected by this line.

The problem is: how do I detect the current topLeft and bottomRight of the visible part of the context according to how much the user scrolled the image? Basically I'd like to add support for a custom viewport, but I can't seem to exploit the scolling information to determine the boundingBox of the chunk to crop from the original image.

Comment: Can you just redraw the area between the two points that a line is being drawn? It sounds like this area would be smaller than the visible area and you already know these coordinates.

Comment: How big is that image? And how can you scroll the canvas contents using the normal scrollbars?

Comment: Yes, I could indeed do this and it would be the easiest way. :) The problem is I could actually need a viewport for future use (you never know), but seems like all of the other viewport questions were related to gaming, so I couldn't find one regarding simple scrollbars.

Comment: @Shomz it's near 5000x5000 and I actually have a canvasDiv container, which is the real scrollable element, not the canvas itself. Sorry for my unclear explanation.

Comment: I see, in that case I think I can help you... was working with much larger files in a game, and got 60FPS... Will write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I actually have a canvasDiv container, which is the real scrollable element, not the canvas itself.

This means your canvas is the full size and you're using the container div as a sort of a "frame". That's really bad as canvas pixels are quite expensive, especially if you're not even using them (they're out of the viewport).

The best approach here is to set the canvas size to the container size and use the drawImage function to control the scrolling. The original image would be places either on an offscreen canvas or an image element. I can guarantee you a much better performance this way.

You'll lose the scrollbars, that's the downside.

Comment: You're right, terrible design choice. At the time I didn't think I would have had to work with images larger than, say, 2000x2000.
I'll figure out some custom scrollbars or something similar, thank you so much @Shomz!

Comment: You're welcome, mate, good luck with it! Remember, never render more than you need to.

Comment: Ouch, I don't use stackoverflow a lot, I thought I could accept more than one answer. :( In fact, both answers are perfect.

Comment: Haha, no worries, welcome to Stack Overflow! :)  You can/should upvote all the good answers (and downvote the bad ones), yet you can accept only one - that's how it works. :)

Comment: Roger :D Until next time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you create the scrollbars by having a larger canvas element contained inside a smaller div.

Instead, you can mimic this setup by:

- Having a canvas the size of your container div.
- Add 2 input type=range controls to act as vertical & horizontal scrollbars (or grab a jqueryUI scrollbar plugin if you want to be fancy).
- Then you can use the clipping version of `context.drawImage` to draw only the portion of the image specified by the range controls. The clipping version of drawImage looks like this:  drawImage(myLargeImage,  clipX,clipY,clipWidth,clipHeight, 0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)

Comment: Exhaustive! Thanks a lot! :D